# Add percentage in input text ? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to add percent sign in input text.

All what I need is this ( identical )

but in Angular. No jquery.

Here is my project.:

Answer (score 2):

You need to add keyup to your input and replace every time the '%' with '' then add it again
i think your code should look like this :
app.component.html

```
   <p>
  Percentage Directive <br/>
  <b>Example: </b> 0 to 100
</p>
<input type="textbox"  #box (keyup)="setvalue(box.value)"[(ngModel)]="InputValue" placeholder="example 22.2" >
 %
```

app.component.ts :

```
  setvalue(value) {
 this.InputValue = value.replace('%','')+"%"    
  }
```

Comment: This is no work . When I try to edit field i got big problem.

Comment: @stev no it does https://stackblitz.com/edit/percentage-directive-in-angular-dmeos6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. He just made a small typo in the placeholder. Please accept his answer.

Comment: u can just add a condition for the empty field i mean if InputValue == "%" change it to empty string idont think that it would be hard

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes sense to add % directly, you can add it when you request it, if you want to display the page, you can use the pseudo element in the CSS display, so the code will be more flexible

Comment: Ok how to do it ?